# the amount of characters in string array that are different from characters of a string

Tags: javascript, string, function, conditional-statements

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
const word = "abracadabra" 

const usedCharacter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "r", "z"]

function (word, usedCharacter) {
returnAmountNotUsedCharacters;
}
```

return the amount of usedCharacters that are not in const word, in this case: "z" is not part of "abracadabra" so returnAmountNotUsedCharacters would return 1

Can anybody shed some light on this? (I am a beginner)

i am trying to figure out the "hangman" game from scratch.
Player has to guess a word by guesing characters, sofar i got it working with a win condition:

```js
function isGameWon(word, guesses) {
  return word.split("").every((c) => guesses.includes(c)); 
}
```

I have a working part of the code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    //if i char of string word is present in guesses, show that char on position i 
    if (guesses.includes(word[i])) {
      wordPlaces += word[i]+" ";
      //put underscores on the not yet guessed characters
    } else {
      wordPlaces += "_ ";
    }
  }
  return wordPlaces;
}

//compare characters of word with characters of guessed, by splitting word() into Word[]
function isGameWon(word, guesses) {
  return word.split("").every((c) => guesses.includes(c));

}

function isGameLost(word, guesses) {

}
```

Comment: We could of course write the code for you, but to help you as a beginner, please explain what your approach was and where you are stuck, and post the code of the attempts you made.

Comment: your question is fuzzy: are the characters in the list unique ?, and if not, should they be repeated when they are not used?

Comment: i am trying to figure out the "hangman" game from scratch. Player has to guess a word by guesing characters, sofar i got it working with a win condition: function isGameWon(word, guesses) {
  return word.split("").every((c) => guesses.includes(c));

Comment: But i have not yet figured out how i can "count" the amount of guesses that are not in the word("word") that are stored in guesses["a", "b", "c"]

Comment: just added some code to the original post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that...

```js
const 
    word = "abracadabra" 
  , usedCharacter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "r", "z"]
  ;
function NotUsedCharacters ( wd, cList) 
  {
  let cSet = new Set([...wd])
  return cList.reduce((sum,c)=>sum+(cSet.has(c)?0:1),0)
  }

console.log( NotUsedCharacters(word,usedCharacter) ) // -> 1
```